# Google spreadsheet left formula with ellipsis

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

I'm using importxml to import some data from an other website. This results in some cells to show long text. I'm using `=LEFT` formula to limit the number of characters in a cell but words stop very abruptly and i was wondering if i can add ellipsis ... (three dots which mean "text continues") to my formula. Something like `=LEFT(B25;600) ...` which should result in "word word w..."
Is this possible?

I tried adding three dots in next cell but they show even when text is not shortened so it does not make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, use:

```
=LEFT(B25; 600)&"..."
```

### update:

```
=IF(LEN(B25)>600; LEFT(B25; 600)&"..."; B25)
```

Comment: Sorry but this shows three dots even when text is under 600 letters. I want three dots to show only when text stops because is over 600 letters.

Comment: It works. I have a further question. Processing speed is very important for me in his file. Does =LEFT(B25;600) is faster than =IF(LEN(B25)>600; LEFT(B25; 600)&"..."; B25) or is the same thing? I mean i can sacrifice three dots for some speed.

Comment: @JohnGrischam its the same thing. but if you want speed you should use ARRAYFORMULA instead per-cell-formula (just my assumption ofc. no idea whats your dataset)

Answer (score 2):

I would only add the ellipsis when there are more than 600 characters

```
=IF(LEN(A1)>600;CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1;600);"...");A1)
```

This formula is from LibreOffice Calc

Answer (score 0):

HERE YOU GO:

=IF(LEN(B25)>600,REPLACE(B25, 600,LEN(B25),"..."),B25)